# Constant shift of Band structure of twisted bilayer graphene along energy axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

I'm trying to reproduce the Band structure of Twisted-bilayer-graphene from M. Koshino's paper: "Maximally-localized Wannier orbitals and the extended Hubbard model for the twisted bilayer graphene", Phys. Rev. X 8, 031087 (2018), but I'm getting a constant shift along the energy axis (see I've attached my result along with the corresponding one from the paper). What could be the possible reasons for this error?

Any comment or suggestion is highly appreciable.Thanks!

[image: The Band structure I'm getting]

[image: Band structure from M. Koshino's paper]

Comment: Some additional detail about what you're doing, and how, would probably make this question easier to answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.